# Can we put public key and private in the same authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, server, putty

I got 2 keys

**A key: generate from server (private key)**

**B key: generate from local ssh-gen**

Can I copy the B-key into authorized_keys along with exiting A key?

Sorry for a simple explanation, but I can't think of more specific examples.

Thanks

Comment: You do not put private key in the `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Anyway, please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok ! Can I put all public key in the auth key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can keep n keep all the keys in the same authorized_keys file

Comment: is order matters ?

Comment: no orders don't matter. Each key needs to be in a new line.

Comment: Not only "can", you "have to", if you want to use multiple keys.